# Some OGG files aren't playing on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Recently (November 15, 2016), Firefox pushed out Firefox 50. It seems that some OGG files no longer work with this version of Firefox.

I have created a simple Fiddle for fellow developers to test it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/mkeqa2m5/

The code is very simple:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ell-random-sharing/st_293_1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls>
  <source src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ell-random-sharing/st_294_1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

If you run the same test on Chrome, everything works fine. But, try it on Firefox and it doesn't work.

Have anyone encounter this issue yet? If you have, what is the easiest way to fix this issue on the code side so that the audio plays on Firefox again. (Any debugging recommendations would be appreciated too)

Update:

1. Just tested this on Firefox 49 and both audio works.

Comment: Did you try [creating a new profile in firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) just to make sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a Firefox bug. See this ticket:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1319543